# slow MySQL database query on several fields and 140k+ records

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-performance

I have the below query:

```
 SELECT ID FROM 

`Article` this_ WHERE
(this_._Temporary_Flag = FALSE OR this_._Temporary_Flag = NULL) AND 
 this_.Published = TRUE AND
  (this_.PublishedOn IS NULL OR this_.PublishedOn <= '2012-10-29 08:54:36') AND 
  (this_.Deleted = FALSE OR this_.Deleted = NULL) AND 
  (this_._ComputedDeletedValue = FALSE OR this_._ComputedDeletedValue = NULL) AND 
  ((this_._TestItemSessionGuid IS NULL OR this_._TestItemSessionGuid = '')) AND 
  NOT (this_.CategoryId IS NULL) 
  AND (this_.PublishedOn < '2012-09-10 00:00:00' AND this_.CategoryId = 51118080)
   ORDER BY this_.PublishedOn DESC LIMIT 1
```

The table in question contains 141,505 records to be exact.  I've checked the indexes and all of the fields mentioned in the `WHERE` clause and `ORDER BY` are indexed (Index Kind: INDEX, Index Type: BTREE).

This query takes 40seconds to run for the first time.  Subsequent runs are down to 1 - 2sec, which I am assuming is due to caching.  If I restart the MySQL Server, it again takes approximately 40 seconds again.  Any ideas why it is performing so slow, and any optimisations that can be done?

**Update 1**

Database is MySQL, and table storage engine is InnoDb.

**Update 2**

As a side-note, the scope of this query is to get the 'previous article', related to the current one.  I am doing this by getting all the articles which have their `PublishedOn` field less than the current ones, ordering by the `PublishedOn` descending and taking the first 1 (I updated the LIMIT as by mistake I originally entered it 50, when it should be 1).

The other conditions are to load only valid articles, and articles in the same category.

**Update 3**: EXPLAIN output

```
SelectType = Select
Type = index_merge
Possible_keys = CategoryId,PublishedOn,_TestItemSessionGuid,Deleted,_ComputedDeletedValue,_Tempo‌​rary_Flag,Published Key = Deleted,_ComputedDeletedValue,_Temporary_Flag,Published,CategoryId
Key_Len = 1,1,1,1,9
ref = (NULL)
Rows = 3383
Extra = Using intersect(Deleted,_ComputedDeletedValue,_Temporary_Flag,Published,CategoryId); Using where; Using filesort ______
```

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN` on this query?

Comment: Edit your question to add that. It is unreadable as a comment. (also, people seldom read the comments because everything should be in the question already).

Comment: @EmilVikström added as Update #3, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `(1) indexed your table fields` and `(2) Partition table` e.g table field PublishedOn are best to `partition by range` You may refer to 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html for more details.

Comment: Can you add a `Partition By Range` to an existing table?

Comment: While I didn't actually try this as it was giving me a 'Foreign Key Exception' when trying to add and it seems you have to re-index everything, this did give me insight into solving the problem.  I've added further restrictions to the query to mimic 'partitioning', and this solved the problem, reducing it from 40sec to less than 1 sec! Great :)

Answer (score 0):

Speed depends of table Indexes. Setup index for `PublishedOn` column.
After that also try to optimize table.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `Article`;
```

Comment: All fields mentioned in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause are already indexed.  I am using InnoDB, so it seems Optimize is a bit useless.